# C#: How to import API Data from web?

Tags: c#

how can i use data from these sample API in a c# script?

This is what i get from the web:

```
[
    {
        "id": "Item1", 
        "valueItem": "100.123456", 
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Item2", 
        "valueItem": "55.23344",     
    }
]
```

I simple need it to be a double like:

```
public double Item1 = 100.123456;
```

Hope you can help, thanks in advance

Comment: That's JSON data, I'd use the Newtonsoft JSON library: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json.net you'd do

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public double valueItem { get; set; }
}

var objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemClass>>(json);
```

You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate your base classes if you need to.

```
foreach(var item in objList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item value: " + item.valueItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that already helps me lot to go forward! If you want to help a little more, how to tell the script the URL where it finds the data?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` knows how to handle a double and therefore, the ItemClass should contain a `double valueItem` property rather than a string.

Comment: Well you should configure the script with the URL, this should be a configuration like a command line item. e..g myscript testurl.com. If you want to play with this kind of thing look at http://httpbin.org/ , it's got loads of test data.

Comment: Thanks @Amir you're right, the explicit parse is not required.